# Creating a URL rewrite rule which creates a URL finishing with a unique set of characters from an id parameter

Tags: wordpress, url-rewriting

I'm developing a WP plugin and have a WordPress URL with an `id` search parameter:

(e.g.: `http://localhost/testsite1/coder/?id=66`),

...which rewrites to...

`http://localhost/testsite1/coder/66`.

The `id` is obtained via a dB query of a record.

How can I convert the `id` to a unique set of characters...

(e.g.: `66 -> h6gt!2`)

...and have a rewrite rule which will create a URL such that...

`http://localhost/testsite1/coder/h6gt!2`

...will actually mirror...

`http://localhost/testsite1/coder/?id=66`?

Comment: Already answered here:
https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/62846/using-custom-dynamic-slug-for-a-page

Comment: No, that question/answer is not helpful as it describes what I already have in place. I have already registered the query variable and have rewrite rules to rewrite /?id=66 to /66. What I want is for /?id=66 to rewrite to a unique short mix of characters.

Comment: What about the answer here:
https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/108286/random-alphanumeric-key-urls

Comment: Do you need to be able to choose and change the `h6gt!2` code? Does it need to be not reversible (cannot find 66 from `h6gt!2`)? Does the `?id=66` still needs to work?

Answer (score 0):

I think you would have to have two things in place:

:: First, a hook on post save that saves a meta property for the post, e.g. `code` and generate a hash or seeded unique code where the id is the seed for the id. You could use e.g.

```
  hash('crc32', 66, false)
```

Mind you, a hash function is never truly unique though. I can come up with a simple random seeded code generator, but again, not sure if this could generate doubles, because I think the random function in PHP is also not truly unique. So you might want to add something even more unique to the code, like a time based value. All depends on how long your code can be.

```
  $table = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789";
  $code = "";

  srand(66);
  for ($i = 0; $i < 8; $i++) {
    $code .= mb_substr($table, rand(0, mb_strlen($table) - 1), 1);
  }
```

:: Second, the page that handles the rewritten url with id -which will handle the url with that code also- would first have to check if the id (which might be an id, but also a code) is in the post_meta table. And if so, get the post that matches that code.